# Uniqueness of a non-convex function with a binary variable

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

for the function f(**x**,**y**)= $\sum_{i=1}^n[(x_i)^{4*y_i} +(1-y_i )lnx_i ] $ ,
**y** are binary variables, **x**  nonnegative real values with fixed upper bound C. Does the minimization min f(x,y) have a unique solution or not?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to make the title a summary, instead of writing whole question there. Also, try to show your own approach, this forum is more for help than doing it all for you. If you want to type math expressions, google "MathJax tutorial".

Comment: How do you define the convexity of a function of a binary variable?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Maybe convexity here is not right. I just wonder whether a unique solution can be obtained for this minimization problem min f(x,y). Could you give any hint on how to consider this uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i$ be arbitrarily close to 0 (and $y_i=0$) and the objective tends to $-\infty$, i.e, the problem is unbounded.

Comment: Does that mean the minimization program may not have a solution? Then what if we give a lower bound of $x_i$, e.g., $x_i>=5$

Comment: Simply study the two functions $x + \ln x$ and $x^4$ and you will see that your function is monotonically increasing and there is a region (from approximately 0.62 to 1) where $x^4$ is the smallest, hence if the lower bound on $x$ is in that region, the optimal  $y$ is $1$, otherwise 0, and optimal $x$ will always be the lower bound.

Comment: Many thanks! I was lost in my own thought. So for this min f(x,y), there always exists a unique solution determined by the lower bound of x. 
If we have some other constraints, does the min f(x,y) also have a unique solution? For example, 
$D=\sum_{j=1}^n(p_j)$ 
and 
$x_i=\sum_{j=1}^m a_j*(p_j)$

where D is a known positive parameter. $a_j$ is known 0-1 variable. $p_j$  is unknown real values.

Comment: Can we say that according to the constraints, decision variables $x_i$ belong to a convex set, and the objective function is monotonically increasing such that the solution is unique?